# Change color for different string in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have a DB in pgAdmin and in one table i have an field named "description" that only can have 2 descriptions: "car" or "bike"
in geoserver i set this label and work well:

```
<Label>
 <ogc:PropertyName>description</ogc:PropertyName>
</Label>
<Font>
 <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
 <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
 <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
</Font>
<Fill>
 <CssParameter name="fill">#b7d5ff</CssParameter>
</Fill>
```

but i want different colors for the 2 possibles descriptions. who is possible in geoserver?

Comment: Yes, use a filter

Comment: i dont  know how, can you help me ?